# Javascript string() function in Google AdWords

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript, google-adwords, google-adwords-scripts

Is there a simple way to implement the Javascript string() function in the basic Google AdWords interface?

I want to pass some variables returned from a campaign management script to a spreadsheet (for comparing future values against historical values), but setValue() only works for strings.

The string() function does not appear to be available in the Adwords scripting interface.

I want to run something like this:-

```
  sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(string(A))
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Coercion in js is amazing and in this case you could simply use like this

```
sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(A + "")
```

Simply plus the empty string to your value.

And for something in the similar but reverse way you can use

```
+myString
```

Just using as a prefix an unary + operator, this will coerce the string to a number.

Find more about js coercion with a super sensei called [Kyle Simpson](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that all I had was a capitalisation error.

It appears to be fine to send function values to the spreadsheet.

In this case the values are numeric, but it appears that the Google Spreadsheet API handles the flattening of int values to strings, so my code now just reads:-

```
   sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(A)
```

And I am a wally.

Comment: The road less travelled around here....

Comment: happens to best of us :-))